# protractor - Not able to find download button in pdf viewer iframe

Tags: angular, protractor

I am trying to write a test case to download pdf from an iframe(pdf viewer), I am able to get to the iframe, but can't find any elements ('the download button') needed to be clicked.

```
it('able to download pdf', function() {
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;        
    browser.switchTo().frame(element(by.tagName("iframe")).getWebElement());      
    browser.findElement(by.id('download')).click();//this is not found and error out
    browser.switchTo().defaultContent();
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;
expect(true).to.eventually.be.true;
```

});

To reproduce simply create an iframe with src to any pdf document, this will open a iframe with the pdf content and download and other options would appear, my requirement is to download it using protractor script.

Comment: I had the same exact issue. Have you resolved this? If yes, can you share what you did? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change:

`browser.findElement(by.id('download')).click();//this is not found and error out`

with:

`browser.executeScript("document.getElementById('download').click()");`

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following:

**browser.actions().mouseMove(elementIdentifier).click().perform()**

Answer (score 0):

Try to console.log() the innerHTML of the iframe first to make sure you switched to the iframe

If you get any error like

> Other element would receive a click at this point of time

then you can use the browser executeScript because some elements in iframe may be over lapped

But from your question i understand that you were not able to find the element that means you have a problem in switching to the correct iframe. You Switch with tag name (i.e) `<iframe>` think suppose there is more than one iframe tags.

Best way is to switch iframe with its source URL mentioning in the xpath attribute

```
//iframe[@src="https://somepage.com"]
```

Answer (score -1):

Tried this suggestion and got an error.
JavascriptError: javascript error: Cannot read property 'click' of null